# How to create a csv and attach to email and send in c#

Tags: c#, .net, email, csv, .net-2.0

This is how i am currently creating a table and sending it in an email. What i would like to do is instead of creating a table and sending it as text in the email i would like to create a csv file and attach it to this email and then send this. could someone please help show me how this can be done? thanks

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv)))
    {
        try
        {
            string to = "";
            string from = "";
            string subject = "Order";
            string body = sb.ToString();
            SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
            MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body); 
            mailObj.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, new ContentType("text/csv")));
            mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { return "{\"Error\":\"Not Sent\"}"; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you already have the CSV file or do you wish to generate it from the SQL data?

Comment: i wish to create new one from the sql data

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Once you have generated the CSV file, you need to write it to a stream.  You can then add the attachment with the following code:

```
//Stream containing your CSV (convert it into bytes, using the encoding of your choice)
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv)))
{
  //Add a new attachment to the E-mail message, using the correct MIME type
  Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, new ContentType("text/csv"));
  attachment.Name = "test.csv";
  mailObj.Attachments.Add(attachment);

  //Send your message
  try
  {
    using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient([host]){Credentials = [credentials]})
    {
      client.Send(mailObj);
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    return "{\"Error\":\"Not Sent\"}";
  }
}
```

Reference for [System.Net.Mail.Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) class

Comment: @Beginner apologies, i have amended my code - initialise the memory stream with your CSV's bytes

Comment: Try initialising the name property of the Attachment object, as in my code above `{Name = "data.csv"}`

Comment: are you sure you are using my code correctly? mine compiles and functions correctly, sending an E-mail with a CSV file

Comment: most likely, instead of using an object initialiser and setting the Name property of the attachment (`{Name = "test.csv"}`), remove that and instead set the Name directly - i will edit my code now to account for this. Object initialisers were introduced in [C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic13)

Comment: @Beginner refer to this link for the format of [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Answer (score 1):

You should look first to create a temporary file (CSV file), then you can add the attachment to your `MailMessage`.
To create the temp file, you can look at these links:
[How to create a temporary file (for writing to) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146/how-to-create-a-temporary-file-for-writing-to-in-c)
[Creating temporary folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656/creating-tempory-folders)